# How do I merge multiple scraped items into one? (Scrapy)

Tags: python, web-scraping, css-selectors, scrapy

Let's say that I want to scrape the text from http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/_static/selectors-sample1.html using the selector

```
response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "image")]/text()').re(r'Name:\s*(.*)')
```

From this, I get the list of items

```
 [u'My image 1',
 u'My image 2',
 u'My image 3',
 u'My image 4',
 u'My image 5']
```

How do I merge the contents in this list so that it will appear as a single line separated by dashes?

```
 [u'My image 1 - My image 2 - My image 3 - My image 4 - My image 5']
```

so I have some sort of forloop in python? or would I have to manually concatenate each when I pull the data from the .json file?

If you need clarification with anything, please let me know!

Answer (score 3):

You should use what's called an `ItemLoader` ([doc](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html)). Basically, this allows you to do other things to the data before it's placed into an `Item`. Check out this code, using your example URL:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import Join

class FooItem(Item):
    images = Field()

class FooLoader(ItemLoader):
    images_out = Join(' - ')
```

Then, in the `parse()` method of your spider/crawler:

```
# get the data
sel = Selector(response)
data = sel.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "image")]/text()').re(r'Name:\s*(.*)')

# load the data and yield an item
my_loader = FooLoader(item=FooItem())
my_loader.add_value('images', data)  # should be the list of strings in your example
yield my_loader.load_item()
```

Here's the output you should see:

```
{'images': u'My image 1  - My image 2  - My image 3  - My image 4  - My image 5 '}
```

The reason this works is that the `ItemLoader` class accepts what's called a `processor` for every field in the class. Common ones are `TakeFirst` (which takes the first matched value) and `Join` (which joins multiple values using the supplied string, or by default, a space). There are others, like `MapCompose` and `Identity`, and you can also build your own. You simply specify the field name and "_in" or "_out", depending on what type of processor you plan on using (input or output). In this case, I named the loader's field `images_out`, because I want the FooItem's `images` field to be processed after the values are returned (output) with a `Join`.

Finally, you probably plan on yielding an item, so the ItemLoader's `load_item()` method does just that: returns an item.